# Azure - what is the difference between DSVM on CentOS vs Ubuntu

Tags: azure, data-science

on Azure there are Virtual Machines pre-configured for Data Science activities. There are images on Windows and on Linux - [CentOS](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm?tab=Overview) and [Ubuntu](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu). My question is - are there any important differences between image on CentOS vs image on Ubuntu? Of course - despite the OS itself ;)

From what I can see in specifications, there are mostly the same, but maybe there are some bits and pieces that have an important impact on using one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory behind DSVM is that there is a build with all of the tools and drivers you need (to run on Azure Nvidia instances)that will work regardless of OS. So the difference is purely an OS one, simply because some organisations have infrastructure geared towards Ubuntu, others towards Redhat/Centos (and some even do Windows!)

The DSVM is an image concept that starts above the OS, so even the Windows editions will have basically the same toolset. if you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/overview) there is a rundown of what the goals of DSVM are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is basically what I assumed, but just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: The CentOS and Ubuntu DSVMs have very similar software, but a few packages are only on Ubuntu. A complete list of installed tools is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/overview.